# How to add .fontWeight as part of a ViewModifer in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I am trying to create ViewModifiers to hold all my type styles in SwiftUI. When I try to add a .fontWeight modifier I get the following error:
`Value of type 'some View' has no member 'fontWeight'`

Is this possible? Is there a better way to manage type styles in my SwiftUI project?

```
struct H1: ViewModifier {
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .font(.system(size: 24))
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
    }
}
```

Comment: Drilling into `fontWeight` indicates that this modifier only works with `Text`. Truth is, I didn't know this either.

Comment: It's very annoying. I have encountered the same problem with shape views. Haven't found a solution yet. :-( I tried all sorts of casting, but to no avail.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can achieve this by declaring the function in an extension on Text, like this:

```
extension Text {

    func h1() -> Text {
        self
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .font(.system(size: 24))
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
    }
}
```

To use it simply call:

```
Text("Whatever").h1()
```

Answer (score 29):

Font has `weight` as one of it's properties, so instead of applying `fontWeight` to the text you can apply the weight to the font and then add the font to the text, like this:

```
struct H1: ViewModifier {
    // system font, size 24 and semibold
    let font = Font.system(size: 24).weight(.semibold)

    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .foregroundColor(Color.black)
            .font(font)
        }
}
```

Comment: +1: I think this is the best solution, as you do not try to fight the SwiftUI architecture by avoiding the use of ViewModifier. Further you can also use it with any "dynamically sized" fonts, e.g. I used `Font.largeTitle.weight(.semibold)` in my application.

Comment: Isn't there some way to require that `content` conforms to a Text protocol or something like that? I'm thinking about generic types.

Comment: While the selected answer works, i think this should be the correct answer because it solves the answer using a viewModifier

Comment: The different between this answer and accepted one is custom view modifiers can have their own stored properties, whereas extensions to View cannot. E.g.  `.watermarked(with: "Hacking with Swift")`.

Answer (score 5):

How about something like…

```
extension Text {

    enum Style {
        case h1, h2 // etc
    }

    func style(_ style: Style) -> Text {
        switch style {
        case .h1:
            return 
             foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.system(size: 24))
            .fontWeight(.semibold)
        case .h2:
            return 
             foregroundColor(.black)
            .font(.system(size: 20))
            .fontWeight(.medium)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can call using

```
Text("Hello, World!").style(.h1) // etc
```

Comment: I like this solution too!